# cmake build .so library

Tags: c++, c, cmake

My `CMakeLists.txt` is here.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(iemoji-lab)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)


add_executable(
        util
        src/util/util.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
        util
        avformat
)
```

After I build, I got `util` executable file. As you see, I have to link util with `avformat` which is in `ffmepg`.

Now I want to build a `.so` file named `libiemoji`.

I have already tried like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(iemoji-lab)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(
        libiemoji
        SHARED
        src/util/util.cpp
)
```

But I got error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_av_register_all", referenced from:
>         GetFrameCount(char const*) in util.cpp.o
>     "_avformat_alloc_context", referenced from:
>         GetFrameCount(char const*) in util.cpp.o
>     "_avformat_close_input", referenced from:
>         GetFrameCount(char const*) in util.cpp.o
>     "_avformat_free_context", referenced from:
>         GetFrameCount(char const*) in util.cpp.o
>     "_avformat_open_input", referenced from:
>         GetFrameCount(char const*) in util.cpp.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libiemoji.dir/build.make:95: liblibiemoji.dylib] Error 1
>   gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/libiemoji.dir/all] Error 2
>   gmake: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2

So how can generate `.so` library?

## EDIT

After @Mario point, I got solution for no error.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(iemoji-lab)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_library(
        iemoji
        SHARED
        src/util/util.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
        iemoji
        avformat
)
```

Now I got a file `libiemoji.dyib`. I am confused by it because I want to generate a file with extension `.so`.

Comment: .so files have a ".dylib" extension on MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got everything right, you just forgot linking the library as well. Copy `target_link_libraries()` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-project should link libraries, similar to executable project; because of dependencies; you can look at [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/)